# Node with text in top left and bottom right rectangle corner

Tags: tikz-styles

I like to define style for the following node:

[image]

So far I manage to do the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart}

\makeatletter
\def\tikzsavelastnodename#1{\let#1=\tikz@last@fig@name}
\makeatother

\tikzset{%
    node distance=0mm and 15mm,
element/.style={%
    draw, fill=white,
    text width=24mm, minimum height=11mm, 
    node contents={},
    append after command={\pgfextra{\tikzsavelastnodename\tikzsavednodename}},#1
                },
subelement/.style={%
    append after command =
    {node[fill=cyan!30,minimum size=3mm, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0.4pt,
          anchor=north west] 
          at (\tikzsavednodename.north west) {#1}}
                            },
subtext/.style={%
    append after command =
    {node[text width=24mm-3mm, %draw, 
          inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt,
          align=center, anchor=south east] 
          at (\tikzsavednodename.south east) {#1}}
                            },
             }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\linespread{0.8}
\node [element, 
       subelement=HB,
       subtext=max. two line long text];
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

This code gives what I like to have, however it has serious weakness: text width is fixed in style. I like to have it as one option for both  styles: `element` and `subtext`. Also I like to have common interface for all style option, something similar as follows:

```
\node [element=<text width> / <top left text> / <bottom right text>];
```

For this I looking how to merge all three styles (`element`, `subelement` and `subtext`) into one, but I quickly recognize that in this I need help of  someone more skilled then I am in the programming TikZ.

**Edit:**
Encouraged with *percusse* comment I try to construct a solution using `path picture`:

```
    \documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning}
    \newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
element/.style args = {#1:#2:#3}{draw, fill=white, 
    text width=#1, 
    minimum height=11mm, outer sep=0pt, node contents={}, 
    path picture={% 
        \node[fill=cyan!30, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0.4pt, 
              below right=\ppbb.north west] {#2}; 
        \node[text width=#1-3mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt, align=right, font=\small, 
              above right=of \ppbb.south east] {#3}; }
                                }% end of style
                            ]
    \linespread{0.8}
    \node (d1) [element=21mm:D1:short text];
    \node (d2) [element=22mm:D2:two line long text];
    \node (d3) [element=15mm:D3:narrow node];
    \node (d4) [element=18mm:D4:two line long text];
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

This solution doesn't work. Error is:

```
Unknown function `path` (in 'path picture bounding box.north west)
```

I don't know, what I do wrong in this MWE.

Comment: why not `path picture`  or actually directly use tcolorbox?

Comment: @percusse, yes this can be a way! I forgot on this possibility. In this case I can use `path picture bounding box` for determine anchors for nodes in corners. I will try this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I made the following solution:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning}
\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0mm,
      start chain = going right,
element/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{name=local name,%
    draw, fill=white,
    text width=#1, minimum height=11mm, outer sep=0pt,
    node contents={},
    append after command={node[fill=cyan!30,
        minimum size=3mm, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0.4pt,
        anchor=north west]
        at (local name.north west) {#2}},
    append after command={node[text width=#1-3mm,
%        minimum height=9mm, text depth=0.5ex, % <-- this doesn't work as expected
        inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt,
        align=right, font=\small, anchor=south east]
          at (local name.south east) {#3}},
    on chain
                                },
                            ]
\linespread{0.8}
\node (d1) [element=21mm:D1:short text];
\node (d2) [element=22mm:D2:two line long text];
\node (d3) [element=15mm:D3:narrow node];
\node (d4) [element=18mm:D4:two line long text];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This solution is very close to what I like to have. Its weakness is formatting bottom right nodes. I also try to construct solution as propose *percusse* in his comment above, but so far I'm not able to resolve errors (see my edit of question). I still looking for better solution :)