# TikZ logo in top corner of shape is not respecting the shape boundary

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I want to include Bash/Python images in a `tikz` flowchart style I am creating so that at a glance it can be seen which programme the process is using (my current project uses both extensively). However, I cannot make the image respect the shape boundary:

[image]

How can the logo be forced into always being in the top left corner of the shape please? I might need to vary heights and or widths of the shapes and cannot profess great knowledge of relative positioning of `tikz`, I tried the self-answer [by @Zarko to Node with text in top left and bottom right rectangle corner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/356424/273733) but LaTeX complained that `local name is not defined`.

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    base/.style = {draw,
                  align=center,
                  inner sep=1mm,
                  },
    python/.style = {base,
                    align=center,
                    minimum height=1cm,
                    label={above left:
                    \includegraphics[height=3mm]{example-image-a}}
                    },
]
\node[python, text width=2cm] (test) {Testing image logo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `label` mechanism has some automations you will need to overwrite:

- Usually, a label is placed on the outside of its parent.
- The anchor of the label will snap to one of the eight main compass anchors (here its south east anchor).
- The label positon `above left` will be interpreted as the angle 135.

You need to use:

- the label position `north west` (meaning the actual anchor `north west` of the parent node),
- the label anchor `north west` as well (to overwrite the automatic `anchor = south east`) and,
- possibly, `inner sep = 0pt` and/or `outer sep = \pgflinewidth` to push the label neatly into the corner, see below.

---

It should be noted that the anchors lie on the outside of the parent node's border which will lead to with just `inner sep = 0pt`
[image]

---

Using `outer sep = 0pt` creates this output:
[image]

The `outer sep` is by default `.5\pgflinewidth` even if the border is not drawn. Use [`outer sep = auto` globally to fix this](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf/outer:sep) or set it to `0pt` when the node is not drawn.

---

It might be best, to use `outer sep = \pgflinewidth` to push the label inside the border but this only works when both nodes have the same line width.
[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    base/.style = {draw,
                  align=center,
                  inner sep=1mm,
                  },
    python/.style = {base,
                    align=center,
                    minimum height=1cm,
                    label={[inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+\pgflinewidth,
                            anchor=north west]north west:
                    \includegraphics[height=3mm]{example-image-a}}
                    },
]
\node[python, text width=2cm] (test) {Testing image logo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]